# php ini settings if done from inside php code and other from php.ini file , which one will override the other?

Tags: php, configuration, ini

If some configuration parameters of php are set from both the modes i.e from inside the php code and from an `php.ini` file .
I wanna know which one will be overriding the other to take effect. and also please tell me if the php.ini configuration is applied in the sub folders or not.

Comment: Then one which you written in your file will be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean `ini_set` then `ini_set` will take precedence over the configuration file.

See [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set).

Note that some values can't be set in this way due to ini_set restrictions or server configuration. `ini_set` will return `FALSE` if it did not set the value (or, presumably, if the value was previously false).